# Getting An Item from IBOutletCollection in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, iboutletcollection

I'm getting an error as "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Here is my code

```
@IBOutlet var customerDashboardButtons:[NSArray]?

var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.tag == %d", tag)
var filteredButtons = customerDashboardButtons!.filter { predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) };
if 0 < filteredButtons.count {
      var button = customerDashboardButtons!.first
      button.hidden = true // getting an error in this line as "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
 }
```

I have tried the following,

```
var button:UIButton = customerDashboardButtons!.first //Error "NSArray? is not convertible to UIButton"

var button = customerDashboardButtons!.first as UIButton //Error "NSArray? is not convertible to UIButton"
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Not regarding your question but still, it is more common in code to use `if filteredButtons.count > 0` than it is to use `if 0 < filteredButtons.count`. It is easier for others to understand your code if you follow those rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet var customerDashboardButtons:[NSArray]?
```

Creates an array of arrays.
Calling `customerDashboardButtons!.first` will return the first array (the `NSArray`) in your array (the `[…]` will also create an array)

I suspect you want your `customerDashboardButtons` to be an array of `UIButton`’s so you would use

```
@IBOutlet var customerDashboardButtons:[UIButton]?
```

Using `customerDashboardButtons!.first` here will give you a `UIButton`. Since the type of the array is `UIButton`, you don’t have to declare your `button` as UIButton.

```
  var button = customerDashboardButtons!.first
```

Will work if you change your array.

Comment: Oh! I see. A small mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example how to create IBOutletCollection and get an Item from it**

**1)**  `@IBOutlet var simpleTextField: [UITextField]!`

**2) Example to get textFiled from that.**

```
for index in 0...(simpleTextField.count - 1)  {
    let textField : UITextField = simpleTextField[index]
    textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```